# Script to check if files in $HOME are owned by $USER and -if not- change them

Tags: bash, authentication, root, startup, chown

Need to create a script at startup that checks if files in $HOME are owned by $USER and -if not- change them.

Would start with
find $HOME ! -user $USER
and later
chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
but can't write it properly to be started automatically as a service at startup in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.You will probably need to run as `sudo`.

```
find $HOME ! -user $USER -exec chown -R $USER:$USER {} \;
```

To execute a command with `find` you can use `-exec` with the command you want to run.

The filename/directory found is inserted into statement as `{}`. And when using `-exec` you have to include a semicolon at the end.

---

If you execute this from a shell script and use `sudo` be sure to use `$SUDO_USER` and `/home/$SUDO_USER` since `$USER` evaluates to root when running a shell script using `sudo`